# how to deal with non-latin character in <?php echo $img->

Tags: php, non-latin

i have the following php code not returned images containing non-latin character,because their links show weird address.

```
if($image) {
   var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($image, 'UTF-8', true))
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($image);
  $imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
  foreach ($imgs as $img) { ?>
    <img data-src="<?php echo $img->getAttribute("src");?>" class="something"/>
  <?php }
} ?>
```

already i have `<meta charset="utf-8">`in `<head>`.how should i deal with this problem.

Comment: Are you sure the HTML loaded into the `DOMDocument` instance is `UTF-8` encoded?

Comment: @chris i'm not.where is this doc?and how can i change its encoding?

Comment: Wrong ping :) @GustavoStraube

Comment: @Hamihamidd, you may use the following fn call: `mb_detect_encoding($image, 'UTF-8', true);`. Docs for `mb_detect_encoding` can be found here: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: Maybe you should try to use `urlencode` for the `src`

Comment: @MrRP, I'm not sure if `urlencode` will work fine if the string is using a different encoding. Could you confirm that?

Comment: @GustavoStraube i simply added this code before my php code: `<?php
    $str = 'áéóú'; // ISO-8859-1
    mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8'); // 'UTF-8'
    mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', true); // false
?>
`    but not worked.is it correct?

Comment: @Hamihamidd, actually, try to wrap the code from my comment in a `var_dump` call, inside your `if` block, to check if it returns `true` or `false`. That will indicate if your `$image` var contains a UTF-8 string or not.

Comment: @gustavo straube you mean : `if($image) {var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($image, 'UTF-8', true););.....` ??

Comment: Exactly that. :)

Comment: Are you working with Angular.js or something like that to use `data-src` in `img` tag?

Comment: @GustavoStraube  i edit my question so that the adjustments have been applied.but the page crashed and not worked.where is the problem?

Comment: @LucasMartins i working with a simple script `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('img[data-src]').....`.also i can use from src,in both case the problem exists

Comment: @Hamihamidd can you paste a src example here?

Comment: @LucasMartins here you are http://www.shop.glassy-garden.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Ø´ÙØ§ÛÙ1.jpg

Comment: @Hamihamidd, you're missing a `;` at the end of that line.

Comment: BTW, the image link you sent is not working.

Comment: @GustavoStraube i made this change but the problem yet stands.just it adds  the pharse " string 5 utf-8" just before `<img src>` tag.the image links i sent are those broken links i faced with.